# A proper chain of principal annihilators in a reduced semilocal ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> I am looking for a reduced commutative semilocal ring $R$ such that there exists a subset $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ of $R$ with $\mathrm{ann}(a_1)\subset\mathrm{ann}(a_2)\subset \cdots\subset\mathrm{ann}(a_n)\subset\cdots$.

Thanks for any help.

A reduced ring = A ring which has no nilpotent element.

A semilocal ring = A ring with finitely many maximal ideals.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ be a field, and let $S=k[[x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, x_3, y_3, \ldots]]$, the ring of power series in two countable sets of variables.  Then $S$ is reduced and local.

Now let $R=S/(x_iy_j)_{j\leq i}$.  Then $R$ is still reduced and local.  Moreover, for any natural number $i$, we have that $ann(x_i) = (y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_i)$.  Hence $ann(x_1) \subsetneq ann(x_2) \subsetneq \ldots$.